# AWS - FailedInvocations with EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I'm currently try to create a cronjob using AWS Fargate and Cloudwatch Events. But it results into FailedInvocations and I don't know why.

First, i've setup the variables:

```
# The AWS region
variable "region" {
  type = string
  default = "eu-central-1"
}

# The application's name
variable "app" {
  type = string
  default = "fargate"
}

# The environment that is being built
variable "environment" {
  type = string
  default = "dev"
}

# The expression for the CloudWatch event
variable "schedule_expression" {
  type = string
  default = "rate(1 minute)"
}

# The tag mutability setting for the repository (defaults to MUTABLE)
variable "image_tag_mutability" {
  type        = string
  default     = "MUTABLE"
}

variable "availability_zones" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "eu-central-1a",
    "eu-central-1b"
  ]
}

variable "task_cpu" {
  type = string
  default = "256"
}

variable "task_memory" {
  type = string
  default = "512"
}

variable "saml_users" {
  type = list(string)
  default = []
}

# locals

locals {
  namespace = "${var.app}-${var.environment}"
  log_group = "/fargate/task/${local.namespace}"
}
```

Then, i've created a user role working with my saml account:

```
# The user role policy document with SAML identification
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "developers" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML"]

    principals {
      type = "Federated"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:saml-provider/simplesaml"]
    }

    condition {
      test = "StringEquals"
      values = ["https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"]
      variable = "SAML:aud"
    }
  }
}

# Create a user role
resource "aws_iam_role" "developers" {
  name                 = "developers"
  description          = "The user role with SAML identification"
  max_session_duration = "43200"
  assume_role_policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.developers.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "ReadOnlyAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "developers_ReadOnlyAccess" {
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.ReadOnlyAccess.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.developers.name
}
```

Also an ECR:

```
# Create an ECR repo at the app/image level
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "app" {
  name                 = var.app
  image_tag_mutability = var.image_tag_mutability
}

# Grant access to saml users
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "app" {
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.app.name
  policy     = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecr.json
}

# The ECR policies for saml users
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecr" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:PutImage",
      "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
      "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
      "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
      "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
      "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
      "ecr:ListImages",
      "ecr:DescribeImages",
      "ecr:DeleteRepository",
      "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
      "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
      "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
      "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
      "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
      "ecr:DeleteLifecyclePolicy",
      "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
      "ecr:StartLifecyclePolicyPreview",
    ]

    principals {
      type = "AWS"

      # Add permission for every saml user since assumed roles can't be wildcard
      identifiers = [
    for saml_user in var.saml_users:
      "arn:aws:sts::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:assumed-role/${aws_iam_role.developers.name}/${saml_user}"
      ]
    }
  }
}

# Returns the name of the ECR registry, this will be used later in various scripts
output "docker_registry" {
  value = aws_ecr_repository.app.repository_url
}
```

Now the VPS which is required:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.10.0.0/16"
}

# Create private subnets, each in a given AZ
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count             = length(var.availability_zones)
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, count.index)
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones[count.index]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
}

# Create public subnets, each in a given AZ
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count                   = length(var.availability_zones)
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 8, length(var.availability_zones) + count.index)
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zones[count.index]
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

# IGW for the public subnet
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}

# Route the public subnet traffic through the IGW
resource "aws_route" "internet_access" {
  route_table_id         = aws_vpc.main.main_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
}

# Create a NAT gateway with an EIP for each private subnet to get internet connectivity
resource "aws_eip" "gw" {
  count      = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc        = true
  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.gw]
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "gw" {
  count         = length(var.availability_zones)
  subnet_id     = element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)
  allocation_id = element(aws_eip.gw.*.id, count.index)
}

# Create a new route table for the private subnets
# And make it route non-local traffic through the NAT gateway to the internet
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  count  = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = element(aws_nat_gateway.gw.*.id, count.index)
  }
}

# Explicitely associate the newly created route tables to the private subnets (so they don't default to the main route table)
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  count          = length(var.availability_zones)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = element(aws_route_table.private.*.id, count.index)
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  name        = local.namespace
  description = "Default security group"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

}

# Allows task to establish connections to all resources
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ecs_task_egress_rule" {
  description = "Allows task to establish connections to all resources"
  type        = "egress"
  from_port   = "0"
  to_port     = "0"
  protocol    = "-1"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.sg.id
}
```

Finally the ECS Cluster and the Cloudwatch Events:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "cluster"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "cron" {
  family                   = "cron"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs-tasks.arn
  cpu                      = var.task_cpu
  memory                   = var.task_memory

  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.app.repository_url}",
    "name": "app",
    "cpu": ${var.task_cpu},
    "memory": ${var.task_memory},
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "portMappings": []
  }
]
DEFINITION
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name            = "service"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.cron.arn
  desired_count   = 0
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
    subnets         = [
      for subnet in aws_subnet.private:
    subnet.id
    ]
  }
}

# Allow task execution role to be assumed by ecs
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs-tasks_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

# ECS Tasks role
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-tasks" {
  name               = "${local.namespace}-ecs"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs-tasks_assume_role_policy.json
}

# Allow task execution role to work with ecr and cw logs
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-tasks_AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy" {
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs-tasks.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

# Events execution role
resource "aws_iam_role" "events" {
  name               = "${local.namespace}-events"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.events_assume_role_policy.json
}

# Allow events role to be assumed by events service
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "events_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

# Setup a scheduled task
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "scheduled_task" {
  is_enabled          = true
  name                = local.namespace
  description         = "Runs fargate task ${local.namespace}: ${var.schedule_expression}"
  schedule_expression = var.schedule_expression
}

# Setup the target for the scheduled task
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "scheduled_task" {
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduled_task.name
  target_id = local.namespace
  arn = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.arn
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.events.arn
  ecs_target {
    task_count = 1
    task_definition_arn = aws_ecs_task_definition.cron.arn
  }
}
```

The only way to launch the Service minutely is to setup desired_count to 1, but i want to setup a 5 minute cron.

Comment: This example is huge and going to be a stretch for anyone to reasonably run. Could you work out a more minimal but still complete example (the guide for creating [mcve]s is great) that still has the same issue you have please? Also it would be helpful to know exactly what error you are getting. If you can edit your question to include the full error and the circumstances that cause it that would be really helpful.

Comment: Tank you for your answer, but  sorry I don't think so... All these parts are required to get a "complete example". Since i don't know the exact reason and AWS tell me nothing except the metric that the invocation has been failed i'm out of ideas to reduce the example. sure, i could take only the last block, but this might no be useful in case of locate the issue. The other option would be to host the code in a gist, but that's not preferred...